# Conditional based Elastic Search Query (if else or Union case)

Tags: elasticsearch

I was working on elastic Query (multiple condition/if else based). My problem is as below

Document 1

```json
{
    "id": "1234",
    "isQualified": true,
    "pending_subjects": null,
    "student": {
        "first_name": "TEST First 1234",
        "last_name": "TEST Last 1234",
        "dob": "01012005"
    },
    "stud_ext_curr_status" :"A+ve" 
}
```

Doc 2

```json
{
    "id": "12345",
    "isQualified": true,
    "pending_subjects": null,
    "student": {
        "first_name": "TEST First 12345",
        "last_name": "TEST Last 12345",
        "dob": "01022004"
    }
    "stud_ext_curr_status" :"A"
}
```

Document 3

```json
{
    "id": "55676",
    "isQualified": true,
    "pending_subjects": null,
    "student": {
        "first_name": "TEST First 565",
        "last_name": "TEST Last 12368845",
        "dob": "01022004"
    }
    "stud_ext_curr_status" :"C-ve"
}
```

Other document

```json
{
    "id": "1111",
    "isQualified": false,
    "pending_subjects": [
                       "MATH",
                       "ECONOMICS"
                      ],
    "student": {
        "first_name": "TEST First 1111",
        "last_name": "TEST Last 1111",
        "dob": "02012004"
    }
    "stud_ext_curr_status" :"A+ve"
}
```

**Doc 4**

```json
{
    "id": "2222",
    "isQualified": false,
    "pending_subjects": [
                       "SCIENCE"
                      ],
    "student": {
        "first_name": "TEST First 21",
        "last_name": "TEST Last 21",
        "dob": "02012004"
    }
    "stud_ext_curr_status" :"A+ve"
}
```

So, I would like to have the records (for both `isQualified` false as well true, but having some specific conditions as below).

```
condition 1) if isQualified is false then 
          a)  Filter all records/documents having non null pending_subjects elements
          b)  Filter above case but for the case pending_subjects element having "SCIENCE"         
               there is need to check stud_ext_curr_status element further to include only if it has "A+ve"
          2) if isQualified is true then filter the document having `stud_ext_curr_status` element value C-ve
```

So, basically output should be Union of docs resulting from Condition 1 & 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine different combinations in should and must clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isQualified": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "stud_ext_curr_status.keyword": {
                    "value": "C-ve"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isQualified": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "exists": {
                              "field": "pending_subjects"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "must_not": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "pending_subjects": {
                                "value": "science"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "pending_subjects": {
                                "value": "science"
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "stud_ext_curr_status.keyword": {
                                "value": "A+ve"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i also did same way during my trial and that worked. Thanks for your answer as well.